# Пунктуация и согласование

Tags: согласование, пунктуация

"В сотрудничестве с различными подрядными организациями, а также генеральными поставщиками и партнерами(,) продукция компании «ОНИКС» поставлена за прошедшие несколько лет на четыре действующие атомные станции; использована при строительстве и перевооружении нефтеперерабатывающих, нефтехимических предприятий, при прокладке магистральных нефте- и газопроводов; смонтирована на предприятия «ТГК-1» и «Мосэнерго» и многих других объектах".

Два вопроса: 1. Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые? 2. Может быть, здесь несогласованно и надо: "смонтирована на предприятиях "ТГК-1", и "Мосэнерго", и многих других объектах".
Или: "смонтирована на предприятия "ТГК-1" и "Мосэнерго" и многие другие объекты."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаемая редакция:

При содействии  подрядных организаций, а также генеральных поставщиков и партнеров, 
продукция компании «ОНИКС» за прошедшие несколько лет ПОСТАВЛЕНА на четыре действующие атомные станции; ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНА при строительстве и перевооружении нефтеперерабатывающих, нефтехимических предприятий, при прокладке магистральных нефте- и газопроводов; 
СМОНТИРОВАНА на предприятиях «ТГК-1», «Мосэнерго» и многих других объектах".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. Обособленный оборот с союзом А ТАКЖЕ является присоединительным.
2. Замена  формы "в сотрудничестве" формой "при содействии" связана с пассивным характером подлежащего (сотрудничает фирма, а не продукция).

Comment: После однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого союзом "а также" или "а то и", запятая не ставится: Бывает трудно, а то и невозможно сразу разобраться в подобной ситуации. Всеобщая грамотность населения, а также широкая пропаганда научных знаний должны способствовать неуклонному росту культуры в нашей стране.

Comment: А здесь нужна запятая:"Журналы, да и некоторые газеты, оказались на грани закрытия".

Comment: С "да и" особая история. Как показывает практика, "да и" соединительный только между сказуемыми: Пошли в лес да и заблудились. Вопрос не о "да и", а о "а также", "а то и", которые вынесены в отдельное правило, видимо, потому, что имеют свою специфику.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза
 у Вас какая-то нечитаемая получилась. Подредактировал, как умею. места 
переносов выделены курсивом, добавления - жирным шрифтом. При 
редактировании исходил из того, что передо мной текст из рекламного 
буклета, если это не так, то возможны некоторые уточнения по стилю.

> *За прошедшие несколько лет*, в сотрудничестве с различными 
> подрядными организациями, а также генеральными поставщиками и 
> партнерами, продукция компании «ОНИКС» **была** поставлена на четыре 
> действующие атомные 
> станции; **использовалась** при строительстве **/** перевооружении 
> нефтеперерабатывающих и нефтехимических предприятий, **а также** при 
> прокладке 
> магистральных нефте- и газопроводов; **помимо этого, она была** 
> смонтирована на предприяти**ях** «ТГК-1»**,**(!) «Мосэнерго» и многих 
> других объектах".

Comment: Совершенно верно. Исходный текст тяжеловат. Редакция текста отличная.

Comment: Спасибо. Не выбираю этот вариант, так как мне кажется нежелательным так сильно менять текст. Но тоже согласна с тем, что на предприятиЯХ.

Answer (score 1):

Позволю себе не согласиться с уважаемой Софией.

Конструкция "При содействии подрядных организаций, а также генеральных поставщиков и партнеров..."  не является присоединительной, это обычные однородные члены, соединенные неповторяющимся союзом.
После слова "партнеров" запятая НЕ ставится.

И, разумеется, на предприятиЯХ.

Comment: "Журналы, да и некоторые газеты, оказались на грани закрытия". Здесь поставлена запятая, также сказано: "особым типом отношений между членами ряда являются присоединительные. Такие конструкции построены на базе синтаксически параллельных членов, но не обладают важнейшим признаком однородности - семантическим и структурным равноправием". Материал из курса лекций для вузов за 2013 год "Синтаксис современного русского языка".

Comment: Снова сошлюсь на Розенталя, имея в виду "да и ..."

У Розенталя аналогичное звучит так:
Присоединительнаяяяяяяяя конструкция может не выделяться с двух сорон запятой, а только отделяться запятой от предшествующей части предложения, если эта конструкция тесно связана по смыслу с последующей частью, от которой в произношениип не отделдяется паузой, например: Поздно теперь, даи не к чему возвращаться к этому вопросу.

В любом случае, я бы не стала ставить запятую, а автор вопроса пусть сам решает.

Comment: В приведенном примере речь идет об однородных членах. Хотелось бы иметь пример именно с такой грамматикой, причем присоединительный член должен находиться не в конце предложения, а в середине, чтобы было видно, отделяется ли он запятой или обособляется.

Comment: "Да и" - присоединительный союз, а "а также" в этой роли мне не попадался. Откуда информация, что "а также" - присоединительный?

Comment: В той же книг есть пример: В съемках фильма участвовали артисты, музыканты, а также местные жители. И второе предложение можно переделать: "Журналы, а также некоторые газеты, оказались на грани закрытия". Нет обособления?

Comment: В той же книге есть пример: В съемках фильма участвовали артисты, музыканты, а также местные жители. Это присоединительный союз. И второе предложение можно переделать: "Журналы, а также некоторые газеты, оказались на грани закрытия". Нет обособления?

Comment: Обособления нет. Видимо, "а также" соединяет семантически равноправные части, в отличие от "да и". А где можно посмотреть значения союзов? Есть специальные справочники?